# Is it possible to display the navigation menu from a Wordpress site on a separate Hubspot site?

Tags: wordpress, menu, hubspot, cross-site

My company has numerous clients that have Wordpress websites with off-site blogs hosted on Hubspot. This becomes an issue with ongoing maintenance when the client makes changes to the main site's navigation without telling us, and the hubspot site then gets out of sync.

Is there a way for Hubspot to actually read and parse the menu items? I've tried making a modified RSS feed, tried iframe and embed codes, tried having HS look into the file structure on WP, nothing is making the connection.